# Parsing "Streaming" JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a grid in a browser.

I want to send rows of data to the grid via JSON, but the browser should continuously parse the JSON as it receives it and add rows to the grid as they are parsed. Put another way, the rows shouldn't be added to the grid all at once after the entire JSON object is received -- they should be added as they are received.

Is this possible? Particularly using jQuery, Jackson, and Spring 3 MVC?

Does this idea have a name? I only see bits of this idea sparsely documented online.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parse incomplete or invalid JSON using the browser's `JSON.parse`. If you are streaming text, it will invariably try and parse invalid JSON at some point which will cause it to fail. There exists streaming JSON parsers out there, you might be able to find something to suit your needs.

Easiest way in your case would remain to send complete JSON documents for each row.

Comment: I think a few projects on Github would disagree:
https://github.com/dscape/clarinet
https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse
https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream
Parsing streaming JSON is possible - probably not for the beginner though, and those are all Node.js projects, I don't know what kind of browser support they have.

Comment: "unless you wrote your own parser to take this into account" I never said it was impossible :)

Comment: "You can't parse incomplete or invalid JSON, unless you wrote your own parser to take this into account." <- not a true statement :)

Comment: Haha, is that a little better?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Oboe.js](https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js/) which was built exactly for this use case.

> Oboe.js is an open source Javascript library for loading JSON using streaming, combining the convenience of DOM with the speed and fluidity of SAX.
>
> It can parse any JSON as a stream, is small enough to be a micro-library, doesn’t have dependencies, and doesn’t care which other libraries you need it to speak to.

Comment: Cant seem to find the docs. Their website is down

Comment: Also, the last commit was 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Lazy.js is able to parse "streaming" JSON ([demo](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/demos/json/)).

Comment: only works for arrays

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[SignalR](http://signalr.net/)**.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Answer (score 0):

March 2017 update:

Websockets allow you to mantain an open connection to the server that you can use to *stream* the data to the table. You could encode individual rows as JSON objects and send them, and each time one is received you can append it to the table. This is perhaps the optimal way to do it, but it requires using websockets which might not be fully supported by your technology stack. If websockets is not an option, then you can try requesting the data in the smallest chunks the server will allow, but this is costly since every request has an overhead and you would end up doing multiple requests to get the data.

AFAIK there is no way to start parsing an http request before it's finished, and there is no way to parse a JSON string partially. Also, getting the data is orders of magnitude slower than processing it so it's not really worth doing.

If you need to parse large amounts of data your best bet is to do the streaming approach.

Comment: But it would be helpful if the data from the server arrives slowly.

Comment: "the difference would be barely noticeable": you do not know this. If the original grid takes up 500MB of memory and the new JSON to be processed takes up 1GB of memory, of which 990MB of memory ends up getting thrown out (say, for example, because it is already in the grid and need not be added), then the streaming approach is likely to make a very big difference in speed, memory usage, and user experience.

Comment: @mwag you are right, I wrote this a long time ago (5 years). I don't know if it is worth it to change my answer or delete it entirely given the original poster isn't likely to be still struggling with this issue

Comment: also, in light of the original question it _does_ make more sense to receive the full object, since parsing individual requests is likely to have much more overhead (there is a limit to how many requests you can make in parallel) and I don't think websockets or HTTP/2 were even a thing back then