# JSON string too large to parse - alternative routes?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have a JSON String that has about 5M Chars but after trying to parse that in to an Array Object I receive the error that the # of chars is too high. Now I thought about looping through the string for x chars and parse that substring but I assume due to some spacing issues in the string, this also threw an error.

Also since I dont actually need the entire variety of properties I thought about deleting this but as far as my research goes, this only is applicaple to JSON Objects themselves.

So does anyone have an idea on how to execute this?

Example Array:

```
{"property1" : "value1", "property2":"value2"},
```

{"property1" : "value3", "property2":"value4"}

I am using google scripts and I am not capable of jQuery so I am looking for a solution that preferably does not require the use of it :)

```js
function getUrl() {
  var headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(getUsername() + ':' + getPassword()), 'Accept': 'application/json' };
  Logger.log(headers)

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': headers,
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  };

 var pimVersion = 5300;
 var url = URL_CATEGORY_PIM + pimVersion
 
 /* ERROR HAPPENS HERE
 * Breakdown reveales that the load for the JSON.parse()
 * is too large
 */
 var categoryData = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText())
 

 return categoryData;
 }
```

Comment: Shortly: read the json as string and split it in to pieces by "},"

Comment: It's not clear at which part in the process the error is thrown, but maybe this helps: [Parsing “Streaming” JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933811/parsing-streaming-json)

Comment: @FelixKling bit the solution was only for Node.js. I don´t know it will be work in pure javascript.

Comment: I haven't used any of them, but there are tools to help with this, things like http://oboejs.com/, or https://github.com/liquidaty/json_streaming_parser.

Comment: Execute What? ... BTW you JSON isn't complete enough to understand the complete issue nor to help you to break it up.  So if we can't see the whole problem or reproduce the error because you haven't provided a [mcve] then we can't help you any further.

Comment: I added the code I am currently using