# TextDecoderStream is producing partial chunk

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I am constructing a reader using `response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader()`.

I then loop through the read output and parse what is supposed to be valid JSON.

The complete implementation can be seen here:

https://github.com/lucgagan/completions/blob/fe34b3fdd9b22f630b8b48f8a07ac87d759ff7db/src/createCompletions.ts

It is supposed to produce output similar to:

```
data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7YkvP6XEACyebJa9awrHeEENrAQNc","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1688517887,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0613","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"role":"assistant","content":null,"function_call":{"name":"print_tags","arguments":""}},"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7YkvP6XEACyebJa9awrHeEENrAQNc","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1688517887,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0613","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"function_call":{"arguments":"{\n"}},"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-7YkvP6XEACyebJa9awrHeEENrAQNc","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":168851788
```

The above is what I get from `reader.read()` [here](https://github.com/lucgagan/completions/blob/fe34b3fdd9b22f630b8b48f8a07ac87d759ff7db/src/createCompletions.ts#L218).

However, notice that the last line got truncated.

I assume this is happening because of some sort of misconfiguration of `TextDecoderStream` or the reader.

What needs to be done to ensure that I am receiving the complete chunk?

Adding [openai-api](/questions/tagged/openai-api) tag because this might be a bug in their/specific to their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each chunk you receive from a `TextDecoderStream` is supposed to be valid UTF-8 text not valid JSON.

To be 100% sure you have all the data, you need to wait for it all to be downloaded, at which point you may just use the `Response#json()` method instead.

Another possible solution would be to use a streaming JSON parser and feed it with each chunk. You can check this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933811/parsing-streaming-json).

Comment: "supposed to be valid UTF-8 text not valid JSON" I meant that the text received is supposed to contain a valid JSON, one per line, to be precise (as illustrated in the sample data I've shared). However, some of the lines get truncated.

Comment: clarified the question

Comment: Yes that's expected, you receive **chunks** of the response. The browser will not check if the data ends where you deem appropriate, it will cut at some byte length, generate an ArrayBuffer from all the latest bytes it received, pipe it to the TextDecoderStream, which will try to decode as much UTF-8 text as it can from that ArrayBuffer and output what it has so far, while keeping the remainder in memory so that it can use it to build the next chunk of text. You need to process all the chunks from that response, but once again, at this point you're just as good using `.json()`.